# Page reading 2 different If-Statements as the same

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm running into a pretty confusing situation here:

```
   if ((a.length == 0 || b === null)) {
        this.noNotif = true;
        console.log("1");
      }
      if (a.length > 0 || b === null) {
        this.newNotif = true;
        // this.noNotif = false;
        console.log("2");
      } else {
        if (a.length === b.length) {
          console.log("No New Notifications");
          this.noNotif = true;
        } else {
          console.log("New notifications");
          this.newNotif = true;
        }
```

Console logging a.length returns 0 and 'b' is null
However, the issue is that somehow both of the first two if-statements' conditions are being met. noNotif and newNotif both display a Vue components and both are showing up currently.

**Some background information about a & b**

'a' is supposed to be data from an API that is fetched on page load. 'b' is supposed to be a localStorage object array

The first if-statement deals with a new user who has no API data or anything stored in LocalStorage

The second if-statement handles when the user does have data in the API, but nothing in LS yet.

The First nested if-statement is if the data from the API matches the LS data

The nested else-statement is if the API data is different (longer) than what's in LS

Comment: They're both being met because `b === null`. What are you expecting? Are you expecting the function to return if the first condition is met? Explain very clearly what you're seeing and what you expect to see.

Comment: Fix your indentation. It'll make your life better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:
It turns out you also didn't put an "else" statement between the two. They're both triggering because they're both registering the || b = null.

```
  if ((a.length == 0 || b === null)) {
    this.noNotif = true;
    console.log("1");
  } else if (a.length > 0 || b === null) {
    this.newNotif = true;
    // this.noNotif = false;
    console.log("2");
  } ...
```

Comment: Good catch, I updated the code and ran it again, but the same thing is still happening.

Comment: Oh, you also forgot to add an "else" between the two statements. It's getting caught on the || b = null.

Comment: Ah, I haven't worked with if-statements in a minute, so the else-if syntax slipped my mind. Thanks for the fix!